# Как создать многомерный ассоциативный массив циклом в php?

Tags: php, массивы

Необходимо получить массив вида:

```
Array ( 
    [028ebaa9-e8dd-4eb3-aec0-2be5632da1fe] => Array ( 
            [deliveryTime] => 2018-05-31 14:47 
            [token1] => token1 
            [tags] => tags1 
            [sendStatus] => sheduled 
            ) 
    [a6352709-47d2-422e-ad84-86ea1249d805] => Array ( 
            [deliveryTime] => 2018-05-31 14:47 
            [token1] => token2 
            [tags] => tags2 
            [sendStatus] => 0 
            )  
    [3716d438-7262-4bda-994d-fe055f4c5b56] => Array ( 
            [deliveryTime] => 2018-05-31 14:47 
            [token1] => token2 
            [tags] => tags2 
            [sendStatus] => 0 
            )
    )
```

Пробовал делать так:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        if ($send_date){
            /*echo "id: " . $row["id"] . " playerID: " . $row["playerID"] . " deliveryTime: " . $row["deliveryTime"] . " token1: " . $row["token1"] . " tags: " . $row["tags"] . " sendStatus: " . $row["sendStatus"] ."<br>";*/
            $playerID = array("playerID" => $row["playerID"]);
            $deliveryTime = array("deliveryTime" => $row["deliveryTime"]);
            $token1 = array("token1" => $row["token1"]);
            $tags = array("tags" => $row["tags"]);
            $sendStatus = array("sendStatus" => $row["sendStatus"]);
            $temp_array0 = array_merge ($deliveryTime, $token1, $tags, $sendStatus);            
            $temp_array = array($row["playerID"] => $temp_array0);
        }
    }

} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
print_r($temp_array);
```

Но, в таком случае получается:

```
Array ( [3716d438-7262-4bda-994d-fe055f4c5b56] => Array ( [deliveryTime] => 2018-05-31 14:47 [token1] => token2 [tags] => tags2 [sendStatus] => 0 ) )
```

Comment: если выводить print_r($temp_array); в самом цикле, то получается три отдельных массива.

Comment: Ну так перед `while` укажите `$arr = [];`, а потом в цикле указывайте `$arr[$playerID] = $temp_array0;` - это как вариант..

Comment: @entithat Ваш вариант рабочий. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$temp_array = FALSE;

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $temp_array[$row['playerID']] = [
            'deliveryTime' => $row['deliveryTime'],
            'token1' => $row['token1'],
            'tags' => $row['tags'],
            'sendStatus' => $row['sendStatus']
        ];
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($temp_array);
echo '</pre>';
```

Если нужна групировка по playerID

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $temp_array[$row['playerID']][] = [
            'deliveryTime' => $row['deliveryTime'],
            'token1' => $row['token1'],
            'tags' => $row['tags'],
            'sendStatus' => $row['sendStatus']
        ];
    }
}
```